# Woocommerce - remove_action not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to modify the function for wc_create_new_customer in Woocommerce, I have added this to my functions.php file...

```
remove_action( 'init', 'wc_create_new_customer');
add_action('init', 'wc_create_new_customer');

function wc_create_new_customer( $email, $username = '', $password = '' ) {
// My custom function
}
```

This is obviously giving me an error as wc_create_new_customer has already been delcared.  How can I modify this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Id like to know a fix for this, trying to change the standard user role from customer to a custom one. this seems the only way I can change it.

However the "fix" above is no good as it dont take the new function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your customised `wc_create_new_customer` (to `my_wc_create_new_customer` or similar) and use that in your call to `add_action`.

Update:

Rather than modifying a core function, you want to use an action to make a custom function run at a certain when a certain event occurs. The `woocommerce_created_customer` event is triggered by WooCommerce when a new customer is created, so you can hook into that action to make your code run:

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'do_things_on_customer_create', 10, 3);

function do_things_on_customer_create($customer_id, $customer_data, $password_generated) {
    // My custom function
}
```

Comment: That makes no difference, the original wc_create_new_customer function is still being called instead of my new version.  I am suspecting the init tag might be incorrect

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed what you were actually trying to do. See revised answer!

Comment: But then wouldn't the original wc_create_new_customer code also be run as well?

Comment: You might need to elaborate on what exactly you want to accomplish, then we can work out how to do it!

Comment: I just want to replace the wc_create_new_customer function with my own

Comment: To completely replace the function, you will need to modify core WooCommerce files (which is bad, as updates will remove your modifications). This is why I suggested using an action. Depending on what exactly you want to achieve, you can probably do so using actions and filters (and without touching core files): http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/